# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am learning Spring MVC and I am blocked since a few hours in this problem, that should have an obvious resolution:

- I am defining in web.xml the DispatcherServlet springSoccer and configuring it in springSoccer-servlet.xml under WEB-INF directory.
- In springSoccer-servlet.xml I am configuring the ViewResolver setting up the component scan pointing to the package of my controller.

I am deploying in Tomcat 8.0 and when I point my browser to http://localhost:8080/SoccerSpringMaven3/springSoccer/users/ I am getting the error:

```
Nov 19, 2015 9:07:50 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SoccerSpringMaven3/springSoccer/users] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springSoccer'
```

It's just a problem of not finding my RequestMapping. Find below the configuration:

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <!-- Source project: sip05, branch: 01 (Maven Project) -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springSoccer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springSoccer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

springSoccer-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.soccer.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

SoccerController.xml

```
package com.spring.soccer.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class SoccerController {

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public String printSoccerHome(ModelMap model) {
        return "HelloSoccer";
    }
}
```

Any pointers?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't you annotate your `SoccerController` with `@RequestMapping("/SoccerSpringMaven3/SpringSoccer")` in order for this to work? Or call directly `http://localhost:8080/users`? The `DisptatcherServlet` cannot find mapping to `SoccerSpringMaven3/` when invoking `HandlerMapping`.

Comment: Case matters!!!!!!!!!!!!! try /SoccerSpringMaven3/springSoccer/users

Comment: RK1 thanks. I tried but it does not work, its my understanding that for the URI first it gets the context root, then the servlet name and then whatever I put in the RequestMapping. My context root as defined in the POM is  <finalName>SoccerSpringMaven3</finalName> then the ServletNAme is springSoccer.

Comment: jny thanks. I tried and again it does not work, there has to be something wrong in the configuration. In Eclipse I can use Spring Tools - Show RequestMappings to show the RequestMappings but in my project nothing appears.

Comment: How do you deploy? what is your servlet configuration in web.xml?

Comment: I am just doing run as - run on server

Comment: Have you tried  /SoccerSpringMaven3/users  ?

Comment: The `<servlet-name>` only defines which `DispatcherServlet` handles specific requests. It doesn't work like `@RequestMapping` annotation. You only configured Spring so that all requests are handled by `springSoccer` DispatcherServlet. Go [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) for more info. Or try just `/SoccerSpringMaven3/users`

Comment: Now it works!!!, OK explain me why please!?. Why I didn't need to write the URI like this context root/servletname/request mapping

Comment: because of this configuration:   `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springSoccer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: I cover all of this step by step in this video: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/springmvc-intro/table-of-contents but your servlet configuration is incorrect.

Comment: I thought that by default I always need to put the servletname. Thanks a lot to you all for the answers. Feel free to post an answer below so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot for your video bh5k will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<servlet-name>` only defines which `DispatcherServlet` handles specific requests. It doesn't work like `@RequestMapping` annotation. You only configured Spring so that **all** requests are handled by `springSoccer` `DispatcherServlet`.

Read [Spring MVC documentation- 21.2 The DispatcherServlet](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) for more info.

In order for this request to work:

`http://localhost:8080/SoccerSpringMaven3/springSoccer/users/`

you have to either annotate your controller with `@RequestMapping("/springSoccer")` or annotate your method with `@RequestMapping("/springSoccer/users")`